# sum of a subarray where each element is less than some specific number

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have an array of n elements unsorted,now a query q comes in a form of l,r,t where l<=r are indices of array and we have to find sum from l to r in a 
subarray where each element must be less than or equal to t.

n<=10^5

q<=10^5

ai(element of an array)<=10^5

t<=10^5

what is the most efficient data structure to solve this problem ?

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: Probably a `std:: vector`.

Comment: tried using merge sort tree,but complexity is still high

Comment: francois ,sorry it was supposed to be t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to effectively answer range queries in an array of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095057/how-to-effectively-answer-range-queries-in-an-array-of-integers)

Comment: Can you modify your array? If so, consider using [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to eliminate the values above `t` and then sum all elements in the requested range. Otherwise, just iterate and count if the value is no more than `t`?

Comment: Francois i think that cant work because i want complexity in logarithmic range

Comment: For each array there may be more than one query?

Comment: You need to create a segment tree. Take values less than t while creating the segment tree.

Comment: *Show an example* Give us a sample array, a couple of sample queries, and the expected outputs. With the addition of the `t` restriction, it seems like the best you can do is O(n): sum all of the items from l to r. And by the way, your explanation says that "q <= 10^5", which doesn't make a lot of sense. Is that supposed to mean that the range (i.e. `r-l`) will be less than 10^5?

Comment: let an  array be like {7,6,14,8,10} now let q=3

Comment: let an  array be like {7,6,14,8,10} now let q=3, (l=1,r=2,t=6,output=6),(l=2,r=4,t=8,output=14),(l=1,r=5,t=9,output=21).

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient data structure is sparse table ( O(nlogn) time to built and O(1) time to query ) or segment tree (O(n) time to built & O(logn) time to query ).